# Redirecting whole Q2A website to HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, https, question2answer

I have been working with [question2answer](http://www.question2answer.org/) and I'm trying to redirect the whole website to https using .htaccess. Problem is there is rewriting going on in the file that gets messed up.

```
 DirectoryIndex index.php
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 #RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
 RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?qa-rewrite=$0&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

 </IfModule>
```

that's what I have so far and if I add

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$
 RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

it does work, but it's messing up the rewriting

```
 RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?qa-rewrite=$0&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

**UPDATE**

With this additional code this is what I get:

```
https://www.example.com/index.php?qa-rewrite=123/this-is-a-title
```

should be:

```
https://www.example.com/123/this-is-a-title
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order of rewrite rules in .htaccess is very important as rules are executed from top to bottom.

Try this code instead:

```
 DirectoryIndex index.php
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 #RewriteBase /

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
 RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?qa-rewrite=$0 [L,QSA]

 </IfModule>
```

Comment: That looks much better than mine, hope that works for the OP. +1 :)